# From Adsense to another advertiser network and maintaining ranking

Tags: google-adsense, ranking, google-ranking, advertising

Currently on my site I have one adsense ad per page in async mode using code as recommended by google. Since my average income is extremely low (due to the adwords network paying nothing), I'm ready to switch advertising networks and remove google.

When I do, what should I watch out for when using the new advertisement code or displaying new advertisements from the new ad provider on my website?

I ask because I feel if I use an ad network other than google, they might give me a lower rank in search results.

Comment: Adsense is not a ranking factor. ;-) But it does motivate Google to do certain things for you. It seems to motivate them. You can have more than one ad network and not dump Google (as an alternative idea).

Comment: For what it is worth, lately my earnings and traffic have been going down. Part of it is a slow refresh, Panda 4.2 (no penalty- just yet another refresh), summer vacations, evening cookouts, surfs up, beers cold, women R warm, etc. Gone from dollars a day to cents a day. But it will go up again in early fall. Takes another nose dive around new years... every year.

Comment: I honestly think its something with the adwords network. Funny thing is yesterday I received paper mail from google asking me to sign up with their adwords. Except they address me as "Business Owner". It makes me wonder if google is filing for bankruptcy soon.

Comment: Don't you know that Google is the new religion?? Google is God. All hail the Google. We sacrifice our young to the G. I have gotten those mailings before but they were addressed to me specifically. It just must be a lazy pooter somewhere. All hail the G! G is the center of our universe. The sun rotates around the G. All hail the G! (just in case they are looking...)